# Is it possible to manipulate dbf headers and fields IE change the order?

Tags: python, dbf

I am trying to make a function that will reorder headers along with their fields:

```
import dbf

table = dbf.Table('somefile.dbf', default_data_types = {'C': dbf.Char})

headerlist = [head0, head1, head2, head3]

def _reorder(x,y):
    z = table._meta.user_fields

    with table:
        z.insert(z.index(x), z.pop(z.index(y)))

while headerlist != table.field_names:
    _reorder(2, 0)
    _reorder(1, 3) #along with any others needed
```

but it doesn't seem that _meta.user_fields is the correct way to manipulate that data.  I'm wondering if it would be easier to write the data in the specific order that I needed to a new .dbf file..

I am likely way off with the code here, just beginning to learn python...  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to reorder the fields is indeed to just create a new database.  I did not make provisions in my dbf module to allow for reordering fields.

If you are trying to present or process the fields in a certain order you can do something like:

```
field_order = ['head3', 'head0', 'head2', 'head1']
for field in field_order:
    print_or_process(my_table[field])
```